# Zero padding pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe, in which col_1 is type integer:

```
print(df)

col_1 
100
200
00153
00164
```

I would like to add two zeros, if the number of digits is equal to 3:

```
final_col
00100
00200
00153
00164
```

I tried with:

```
df.col_1 = df.col_1.astype(int).astype(str)

df["final_col"] = np.where(len(df["col_1"]) == 3, "00" + df.col_1, df.col_1 )
```

But it doesn't produce the expected output (it doesn't add the two digits when the condition is satisfied).

How can I solve that?

Comment: use `df['col_1'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)`

Comment: you need to just cast your value as string (`str`) and zero fill (`zfill`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# after converting it to str , you can foolow up list comprehension.

df=pd.DataFrame({'col':['100','200','00153','00164']})
df['col_up']=['00'+x if len(x)==3 else x for x in df.col ]
df

###output

    col    col_up
0   100     00100
1   200     00200
2   00153   00153
3   00164   00164


    ### based on the responses in comments 
  %%timeit -n 10000
 df.col.str.pad(5,fillchar='0') 
142 µs ± 5.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)


     %%timeit -n 10000
 ['00'+x if len(x)==3 else x for x in df.col ]
21.1 µs ± 952 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

  %%timeit -n 10000
  df.col.astype(str).str.pad(5,fillchar='0')
243 µs ± 7.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: :/ this is a weird way to achieve this. I think the str.pad and str.zfill approaches are MUCH more normal ways to do this.

Comment: I just wanted to provide a different way  to achieve , other ways zfill , pad , were already covered. for more efficient code , we surely wana have zfill and pad.

Comment: The whole point of answering questions in SO is to help other users with the best solution possible to a given problem. Not just  *another answer*, different to what has been posted, at the expense of clarity and performance

Comment: @yatu  i have  added the time taken to achieve the  final output for all the solutions posted here. I do understand , your point , but there is no harm to provide an answer which is easy for the questioner. From all the solutions, he have a choice what suits him/her or for his current setup.

Comment: This is not representative. Try with a larger dataframe

Comment: @vrana95 also, your tests aren't equivalent, you've astype str one of the methods, but your solution assumes they start as strings, and you haven't accounted for the difference between writing a series onto a df vs writing a list onto a df - but most of all the issue here isn't really about timing, it's a question of readability and style. I know that this isn't necessarily the way you would achieve this yourself, and that you wrote it to provide an alternative, I just don't think it's a good idea to provide worse alternatives. I should get back to work though!

Answer (score 14):

Another way using [`series.str.pad()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.pad.html):

```
df.col_1.astype(str).str.pad(5,fillchar='0')
```

---

```
0    00100
1    00200
2    00153
3    00164
```

You solution should be updated to:

```
(np.where(df["col_1"].astype(str).str.len()==3, 
       "00" + df["col_1"].astype(str),df["col_1"].astype(str)))
```

But this will not work when the length of the string is less than 5 and not equal to 3, hence I recommend you to not to use this.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['final_col'] = df['col_1'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
```

[out]

```
   final_col
0      00100
1      00200
2      00153
3      00164
```

---

Update, if you only want to pad where len is 3 exactly, use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) *Thanks @yatu for pointing out*:

```
df.col_1.where(df.col_1.str.len().ne(3),
               df.col_1.astype(str).str.zfill(5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `col` column's data type is `str`, you can extract string using `.str` and use `.pad()` to pad the string up to width = 5 with 0 `.pad(5, fillchar='0')`.

Check the [documnetation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.pad.html)

```
IN[1]:  df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['100','200','00153','00164']})
        df
```

```
Out[1]:
    col
0   100
1   200
2   00153
3   00164
```

```
In[2]:  df['final_col'] = df.col.astype(str).str.pad(5, fillchar='0')
        df
```

```
Out[2]:
    col final_col
0   100     00100
1   200     00200
2   00153   00153
3   00164   00164
```

Also, you can convert the data types -*if the column's data type is not a string*- using `.astype(dtype)` to convert it to string and then use `.pad()` on it.